# How to select row pairs from a large table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

In table.....(ID, NAME, EVENT)

Data:

```
(1,BOB,E)    
(2,JANE,B)    
(3,JOE,C)    
(4,TOM,A)   
(5,JANE,B)    
(6,JOE,C)    
(7,BEN,D)    
(8,TOM,B)    
(9,JANE,D)    
(10,JOE,A)    
(11,JANE,B)    
(12,BOB,C)    
(13,JOE,C)    
.    
.    
.
```

Desired Output:

```
(2,JANE,B)    
(3,JOE,C)    
(5,JANE,B)    
(6,JOE,C)
```

I'm trying to list out each instance where Jane,B and Joe,C appear in the table consecutively.  Using sqlite.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's common to those pairs? That will help you pull them out. :-) if you specify the names and event in where clause with '`IN` operator, doesn't it do the job?

Comment: I just took my answer back, as I HAVE TOTALLY SKIPPED YOUR MOST IMPORTANT REQUIREMENT : CONSECUTIVE RECORDS.... :) Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with standard SQL, which also works on SQLite.  The idea is to join a given row to the next and previous rows, and then check for the conditions:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tnext
     on tnext.id = t.id + 1 join
     t tprev
     on tprev.id = t.id - 1
where (t.name = 'Jane' and t.event = 'B' and tnext.name = 'Joe' and tnext.event = 'C') or
      (tnext.name = 'Jane' and tnext.event = 'B' and t.name = 'Joe' and t.event = 'C') or
      (t.name = 'Jane' and t.event = 'B' and tprev.name = 'Joe' and tprev.event = 'C') or
      (tprev.name = 'Jane' and tprev.event = 'B' and t.name = 'Joe' and t.event = 'C')
```

Comment: Hey Gordon :) nice answer, btw the lat `OR` is causing an error. I think OP would notice it. :)